# Should I use <section>,<div> or <article> here? I don't want to catch the 'div' flu

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm starting to learn semantical HTML, and I'm a little bit confused. I've read a lot about these tags, but I still don't know which one to use. I'm creating a personal portfolio and this is part of the landing page :

```
 <section> 
  <div>
    <h2>Who am I?</h2>
    <p>I'm <b>Nolan Knefati</b>, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla voluptatibus distinctio quisquam, adipisci officia necessitatibus iusto! Tempore quos a illum, perspiciatis fugiat expedita consequuntur maxime voluptate reprehenderit beatae, explicabo iure!.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>What sort of services do I offer?</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia voluptas totam, minima eaque eveniet eos distinctio labore fugit dolorem, vel molestiae laudantium unde deserunt voluptatem reprehenderit aliquid repellat rem hic.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Some projects I have worked on</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem earum veniam quas, debitis neque molestias perferendis eius, beatae nobis enim corrupti dolor non eligendi magni tempore fugiat quibusdam itaque delectus?</p>
  </div>
  <a href="contact.html" class="standardbutton">I want to hire you</a>
</section>
```

I do want to avoid catch the "div" flu, that's why I'm trying to see how to write this semantically better.

Comment: Ii would use `<section>`. Note: sections should have headings. So this would fit your usage perfectly.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element

Comment: Do I have to use <section> to wrap the other elements? Or should I delete it and it'll behave the same, talking about SEO? I mean, I don't want to put any H on the <section> that is wrapping the <div> elements as you can see in the code. But I put in there because I think all these elements should be within a tag to improve the semantic.

Answer (score 1):

Right, according to your answers I have modified the code as follows:

```
<main>
  <section>
    <h2>Who am I?</h2>
    <p>I'm <b>Nolan Knefati</b>, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla voluptatibus distinctio quisquam, adipisci officia necessitatibus iusto! Tempore quos a illum, perspiciatis fugiat expedita consequuntur maxime voluptate reprehenderit beatae, explicabo iure!.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>What sort of services do I offer?</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia voluptas totam, minima eaque eveniet eos distinctio labore fugit dolorem, vel molestiae laudantium unde deserunt voluptatem reprehenderit aliquid repellat rem hic.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Some projects I have worked on</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem earum veniam quas, debitis neque molestias perferendis eius, beatae nobis enim corrupti dolor non eligendi magni tempore fugiat quibusdam itaque delectus?</p>
  </section>
  <a href="contact.html" class="standardbutton">I want to hire you</a>
</main>
```

I changed **div** for **section** because of its semantical use, and replace the **section tag**, that was wrapping the elements, for **main**, for the reason that it does represent the dominant content of the body and I did not want to put an **H** there.

This is how the code goes after all your tips.

```
<main>
  <h1>Welcome, I'm Nolan.</h1>
  <img src="Media/Ferret.jpg" alt="A ferret enjoying the snow, also looking at you" class="presentationpicture" title="Most recent Nolan's portrait">
  <section>
    <h2>Who am I?</h2>
    <p>I'm <b>Nolan Knefati</b>, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla voluptatibus distinctio quisquam, adipisci officia necessitatibus iusto! Tempore quos a illum, perspiciatis fugiat expedita consequuntur maxime voluptate reprehenderit beatae, explicabo iure.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>What sort of services do I offer?</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia voluptas totam, minima eaque eveniet eos distinctio labore fugit dolorem, vel molestiae laudantium unde deserunt voluptatem reprehenderit aliquid repellat rem hic.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Some projects I have worked on</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem earum veniam quas, debitis neque molestias perferendis eius, beatae nobis enim corrupti dolor non eligendi magni tempore fugiat quibusdam itaque delectus.</p>
  </section>
  <a href="contact.html" class="standardbutton">I want to hire you</a>
</main>
```

I had the H1 within the header tag, but I moved it to support the main tag, so, as understood, it would be semantically better.

Comment: This looks good, but make sure you also have an `<h1>` that titles the document within the `<main>` and before the subsections. The first heading in a document shouldn't be an `<h2>`.

Comment: @Sean, oh, it isn't the first heading in the document, I already have an h1 within the header section. But, are you saying I should add one under the main tag as well or just put the one in the header there?

Comment: You should only have one `<h1>` for the document, and ideally it would be within the `<main>`, since it's the main heading of the document.

Comment: Thank you, @Sean. I already updated the post with the fixed code!

Comment: You should update your answer with that content, instead of the question. It's best practice to not edit questions to include the solution, once found.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).